# Cisco nexus spanning-tree logging to syslog

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-nexus, syslog

I am trying to send my spanning-tree events to remote syslog but somehow it doesn't work, This is what i have in my config.

```
N3K# sh run | grep logg
logging level spanning-tree 7
logging server 172.29.0.91 5 use-vrf management
logging origin-id hostname
```

I can see all other logs on syslog coming from that switch but none from STP. what i am missing?

Comment: Can spanning-tree logs be found in the `show logging log` command?

Comment: NO nothing in `show logging logfile` command, i can see all other logs but not STP

Comment: I think it's because the log level is 7. Adjust logging level 4 or lower for logging level configuration 7 tests with command `logging level spanning-tree 4`. This can generate an enormous amount of logs.

Comment: Can you explain why need to go below 4 or below?

Comment: I didn't like i have changed log level to 4 but no luck :(

Comment: Because there are no STP logs in the result of `show logging log` command, there are two possible reasons. The first is the is no STP events. Another possibility is that log events are filtered at the log level. And I guessed that the log level would be glitched and filtered.

Comment: Make sure that STP works well with the `show spanning-tree [vlan]` command. Logging may not occur if an event does not occur. In some cases, you may need to use `debug [xxx]` commands.

Comment: to generate STP logs or event i am manually shutting down one of tunnel to converge STP and i can see STP getting converge & event in `show spanning-tree internal event-history all` command output. I can tell you STP is generating event but not able to make it in logging somehow.